# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```js
class Point {

    private x: number;
    private y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    public distance(otherPoint: Point): number {
      return Math.sqrt(
          Math.pow(this.x - otherPoint.getX(), 2) +
          Math.pow(this.y - otherPoint.getY(), 2));
    }

    public getX() {
      return this.x;
    }

    public getY() {
      return this.y;
    }

  }

  class Circle {

    private center: Point;
    private radius: number;

    constructor(center: Point, radius: number) {
      this.radius = radius;
      this.center = center;
    }

    public isInside(otherPoint: Point): boolean {
      return this.center.distance(otherPoint) < this.radius;
    }

  }

  class Triangle extends Point {
      private z: number;

      constructor(x:number, y: number, z: number){
          super(x, y);
          this.z = z;
      }

    public getZ(){
        return this.z
    }

    public getPerimeter (otherPoint: Triangle): number{
        return otherPoint.getX() + otherPoint.getY() + otherPoint.getZ()
    }
  }

  let per = new Triangle(24, 61, 32);
  console.log(per);
```

so when i try to compile it says

```
private x: number;
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Are you compiling it with Typescript ?

Comment: yes our work is to do it only with type script private mostly

Comment: You are writing the code using Typescript syntax, but i mean, are you compiling it using Typescript compiler or you just run it with `node` command ? Could you please post how you are running the code ?

Comment: i run it with a node command node oop.ts -> filename

Comment: Well. you meed to install Typescript on your machine then compile your Typescript code into Javascript ode to be able to use `node oop.ts `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am pretty sure either there is formatting issues or you are using a compiler which does not like the syntax, but here is the code i executed in  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/  and it worked perfectly fine.

```
    class Point { 
    private x: number;
    private y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    }

    public distance(otherPoint: Point): number {
    return Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(this.x - otherPoint.getX(), 2) +
        Math.pow(this.y - otherPoint.getY(), 2));
    }

    public getX() {
    return this.x;
    }

    public getY() {
    return this.y;
}
}

class Circle { 

    private center: Point;
    private radius: number;

    constructor(center: Point, radius: number) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.center = center;
    }

    public isInside(otherPoint: Point): boolean {
    return this.center.distance(otherPoint) < this.radius;
    }    
}

class Triangle extends Point {
    private z: number;
    constructor(x:number, y: number, z: number) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public getZ() {
        return this.z
    }

    public getPerimeter(otherPoint: Triangle): number {
        return otherPoint.getX() + otherPoint.getY() + otherPoint.getZ()
    }

}

let per = new Triangle(24, 61, 32);
console.log(per);
```

Run above code in the link that i mentioned, hit "Run" and hit "F12" to open the console, you will see the output from console.log

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a TypeScript file as if it were JavaScript. JavaScript and TypeScript are not the same, and `node` can only understand JavaScript, not TypeScript.

You need to install the packages `typescript` and `ts-node`. You can do so globally so that you can use it everywhere, for individual files:

```sh
npm i -g typescript ts-node
```

Afterwards, you can use `ts-node` instead of `node` to run your file:

```sh
ts-node myScript.ts
```

This will compile your TypeScript file to JavaScript on the fly and run the result with `node` for you.

Comment: ok so i figuerd where i got stu**d the command to make a js file is npx tsc oop.ts and then to run it i hit node oop.JS sorry everyone :D